# Why do custom Application Pages produce exceptions after installing June 2011 CU?

Tags: 2007, application-pages, cumulative-update

We recently applied the June 2011 Cumulative Update on our MOSS 2007 servers and had the February 2011 CU before that.

Since we installed the June CU all our custom application pages (e.g. an ASP.NET page that opens when you click on "New" in a SharePoint list) throw the following exception when doing any kind of postback (no submit, just a "normal" postback e.g. to switch to the edit mode in an ASP.NET ListView) directly after the completion of the Page_Load method.

> Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException
>
> Message:
>   The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.
>
> Stacktrace:
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ValidateFormDigest(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ValidateFormDigest() 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest() 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.EntityEditor.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> Inner Exception 1:
>   Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>
> Message:
>   The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.
>
> Stacktrace:
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ValidateFormDigest(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ValidateFormDigest(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName)

Normally this exception indicates that you forgot to set SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true somewhere in your code...but this was workng before installing the June CU, so I was wondering if anyone else has the same issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue except that it only occurs when adding a new link the summary link web part. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: @Jason Install August CU for both Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 (KB 2553022) and Office SharePoint Server 2007 (KB 2553020). For the error refer : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be a problem related to a problem related to FormDigest. See if the pointers below help you understand your problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472879.aspx

http://epham.wordpress.com/2007/01/22/how-to-fix-security-validation-errors-in-sharepoint-aspnet-page/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also found out that this is part of the solution, but now I've got the same issue as Christian below that a PeopleEditor causes an Exception when switching an ASP.NET ListView to edit mode...

Answer (score 3):

I found out that not only the custom application pages have this problem. The dialog.master also have the same problem.
We fixed this by adding the formdigest before the end of the  tag.